# How to implement href attribute in facebook notification?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

From FB  oficial documentation

> When people click the notification, they'll be taken to a URL you
>    specify with the notification.

I have been strugling to understand what canvas app actually is. I have managed to actually send and recieve notification, however when clicking to notification fb redirects me to `apps.facebook.com/1111111111111111/home?fb_source=notification&fb_ref=test` where a lot of 1`s is meant my app id(did not know if I should protect that so better protect) and "home" is href I specified in href parameter when making post to userid/notifications endpoint. The first part is exactly as in my settings tab listed canvas page but I can not change it.

I expected that on click I would be  redirected to my website. Could some one please explaine me what have I misunderstood? I think the problem is that I really do not understand what fb canvas app is and how it works.

Comment: _“I expected that on click I would be redirected to my website”_ - no, it takes them to the canvas app. (And you are not allowed to set up a canvas app with the sole purpose of redirecting people off of Facebook.)

Comment: Thank you for clarifying it. Just be sure that I have got it correctly, if I want to notify user to their Facebook account I should read more about canvas page and build proper canvas page?

Comment: First of all you should think about whether you actually have a proper use case to send notifications on Facebook. If you just have an external website with no connection to/use of Facebook features - then I’d say, it rather isn’t.

Comment: I am really confused with facebook dev docs. I have native authorization mechanism on my site and also "continue with facebook" login. If user registers with e-mail(native mechanism) I send emails to him when new event happens(if he is not online). If user uses fb to access my site member-only part I want to use facebook notification instead of email. I consider that to be more user-friendly than e-mail notifications. That count as properuse case? And if not - will fb block my app in some way?

Comment: Depends mainly on whether you are actually presenting content to the user inside the canvas, and keep them there. (Again, using canvas merely to redirect them outside of Facebook is not allowed.) And there is also a certain click-through-rate that your notifications need to achieve. If Facebook thinks you are sending to many notifications that people don’t actually care about, your app might be blocked from sending notifications.

Comment: Ok, about the click-through-rate I am very confident that there will be no problems because notification will be important to user and also there will be option to chose "not send notifications to fb". About content -  I will have two important types of notifications. 1.A new item near you has been added to my site. In this case I could display the information about item in canvas. 2. A new acitivity has happened in conversation(inner chat system of my site) with another user. In this case I could display information associated with conversation(conversation are about items). Would that be ok?